# How to check if key of key of object is undefined

Tags: javascript

Let's define an object.

```
const obj = {};
```

We can check that obj.x is undefined since we can control it like that:

```
if(typeof obj.x === "undefined") console.log("error");
```

However, how can I also check if obj.x.y is undefined withouth try, catch block.

```
if(typeof obj.x.y === "undefined") console.log("error"); // Throws and error
```

I'm doing and application which gets response from a server and I need check object like error.response.data.error.message is undefined or not.

Comment: `typeof obj.x === "undefined" && typeof obj.x.y === "undefined"`. Although it's much shorter as `obj.x && obj.x.y`

Comment: Or you can use optional chaining like `ìf(obj?.x?.y)`

Comment: Like this `if(obj?.x?.y)`.
This is called Optional Chaining. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)